# Magento 2: How to get selected shipping address from shipments page?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

Is there any way we can get the Selected shipping address object from Magento 2 Shipments page?
Was trying to search for it like an observer but getting solutions only when you are on checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

Override the core file in your custom module Vendor/Modulename

> Namespace/ModuleName/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service' : 
            'NameSpace_ModuleName/js/model/shipping-service'      
        }
  }
};
```

> Namespace/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-service.js

```
/*global define, url*/
define(
[
    'jquery', // For jQuery Added
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote', // For Quote Added
    'ko',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver'
],
function ($, quote, ko, checkoutDataResolver) {
    "use strict";
    var shippingRates = ko.observableArray([]);
    return {
        isLoading: ko.observable(false),
        /**
         * Set shipping rates
         *
         * @param ratesData
         */
        setShippingRates: function (ratesData) {
            if (loggedinCustomer == 1) {

                // you can get address of current shipping address here
                var address = quote.shippingAddress();

                   
                // STOP TO REMOVE ERROR MESSAGE FOR DHL IF SG

                shippingRates(ratesData);
                shippingRates.valueHasMutated();
                checkoutDataResolver.resolveShippingRates(ratesData);
            }
        },

        /**
         * Get shipping rates
         *
         * @returns {*}
         */
        getShippingRates: function () {
            return shippingRates;
        }
    };
  }
);
```

> This Line : var address = quote.shippingAddress();

After that run upgrade,compile, deploy commands